# How to design an xsd for multiple choice questions?

Tags: xml, xsd, schema, processor, multiple-choice

Right now I have a system that allows users to create multiple choice questions. A user (idealy) would use them like this:

```
<MultipleChoice>
   <Choices>
      <Choice>a) apple</Choice>
      <Choice>b) banana</Choice>
      <Choice correct="true">c) grapes</Choice>
   </Choices>
</MultipleChoice>
```

Notice the correct attribute on grapes. That is used so that when I render it in the UI there is a green check mark next to it. However, with my current xsd I can't prevent the user for not putting any correct="true" attribute at all or putting it for multiple choices.

Examples of what I don't want users to be able to do are the following:

**No correct choice (don't let users do this)**

```
<MultipleChoice>
   <Choices>
      <Choice>a) apple</Choice>
      <Choice>b) banana</Choice>
      <Choice>c) grapes</Choice>
   </Choices>
</MultipleChoice>
```

**Multiple correct choices (don't let users do this)**

```
<MultipleChoice>
   <Choices>
      <Choice>a) apple</Choice>
      <Choice correct="true">b) banana</Choice>
      <Choice correct="true">c) grapes</Choice>
   </Choices>
</MultipleChoice>
```

How can I restrict users of my schema to be able to define one and only one correct choice? What I mean is I should be able to give them an error if they have violated the **one and only one** correct answer rule.

Here is my current schemas

```
...
<xs:complexType name="MultipleChoice">
   <xs:complexContent>
       <xs:element name="Choices" type="Choices" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
   </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="Choices">
   <xs:sequence>
       <xs:element name="Choice" type="Choice" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1"/>
   </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="Choice">
   <xs:simpleContent>
       <xs:extension base="xs:string">
           <xs:attribute name="correct" type="xs:boolean" default="false"/>
       </xs:extension>
   </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

Comment: I'm tempted to say that all sufficiently interesting questions have more than one correct answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way would be to define it as a seperate element and restrict it's use to only one. So my suggestion would be to define it like this:

```
<xs:complexType name="MultipleChoice">
   <xs:complexContent>
       <xs:element name="Choices" type="Choices" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
   </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="Choices">
   <xs:sequence>
       <xs:element name="Choice" type="Choice" maxOccurs="3" minOccurs="1"/>
       <xs:element name="CorrectChoice" type="CorrectChoice" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1"/>
   </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="Choice">
   <xs:simpleContent>
       <xs:extension base="xs:string"/>
   </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="CorrectChoice">
   <xs:simpleContent>
       <xs:extension base="xs:string"/>
           <xs:attribute name="correct" type="xs:boolean" default="false" use="required"/>
       </xs:extension>
   </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

Otherwise if you are using XML 1.1 and want to keep the element `Choice` by itself then you could solve it by using an assert that checks and counts how often you use the attribute `correct`. Something like this should work:

```
<xs:assert test="count(Choices//@correct) le 1"/>
```

This assert will limit the number of attributes `correct` that can be applied within one element `Choices` to 1. So any element `Choices` with more then one `Choice` that has the attribute correct will fail.